# Subimage pattern paints black on HTML platform

Tags: playn

I am using PlayN 1.8

I load an image sprite and on success callback I extract a subimage from the original.

```
Image patternImage = result.subImage(0f, 0f, 10f, 10f);
```

Then I create the actual image I want to display:

```
CanvasImage image = PlayN.graphics().createImage(50f, 50f);
```

I create a path

```
Path path = image.canvas().createPath();
```

I path the path to a hexagon shape

I close the path

```
path.close();
```

I create a pattern

```
Pattern pattern = patternImage.toPattern();
```

I paint the canvas with the newly created pattern

```
image.canvas().setFillPattern(pattern);
image.canvas().fillPath(path);
```

On Java Platform this works beautifully but on HTML platform the shape defined by the path is completely black as if the image was not loaded. In Chrome console I do see, however, the image being downloaded correctly. Also, I tried to fill the path with a solid color which works fine. So my question here is why does my path paints black?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the HTML platform canvas does not fill with pattern if the pattern has `repeat-x` and `repeat-y` both set as `false`.

HtmlCanvas.java

```
public CanvasPattern pattern(Context2d ctx) {
  Context2d.Repetition repeat;
  if (repeatX) {
    if (repeatY) {
      repeat = Context2d.Repetition.REPEAT;
    } else {
      repeat = Context2d.Repetition.REPEAT_X;
    }
  } else if (repeatY) {
    repeat = Context2d.Repetition.REPEAT_Y;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
  return ctx.createPattern(patimg, repeat);
}
```

Looking at that code I see that a `null` is returned instead of using `Context2d.Repetition.NO_REPEAT`. Hence, there is no fill pattern and the path is filled with the default fill color which is black. I tested this and this really seems to be the case here. Now I get my patterns nicely filled with correct images.

Pauli Savolainen